# Centering a container with and without a scrollbar under each other

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm having a problem with what seems to be an easy thing to do...

**What I would like to achieve:**

A fixed header that is aligned center and always stays in the same place.
The content-container below needs to be centerd as well, but can be animated offscreen. This should act like a one-page app (no refresh). The first content-container needs to hold it's scroll-position (because it's an infinite scroll), the second acts as a detail-page.

Please take a look at the example so you understand it correctly (difficult problem to explain).

**Codepen (example):**

http://codepen.io/IbeVanmeenen/pen/AtDKG

**Where is the problem?**

- The scroll doesn't really play nice in all browsers.
- Because of the scrollbar in the content-container, the content isn't centerd below the header correctly. This happens where the scrollbar-width is calculated in the width (Chrome and IE under Windows)

Does anyone have an idea to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you could try using a JavaScript library to fix the compatibility issues in the JavaScript. addEventListener will only work in >= IE9, anything less, this code will break. You could use jQuery's 'on' method for event binding.

```
$('element').on('click', doSomething);
```

Comment: Yeah, >=IE9 is not really a concern for this project... Problem is css wise... how to center this...

Answer (score 0):

i see the text container is slightly centered too much to the left because of the scrollbar so i would correct it with something like

```
.center-container.text {
  position: relative;
  left:10px; /* size of scrollbar /2 */
}
```

but guess i don't understand the issue completely :)

Answer (score 0):

Try giving each one these CSS properties:

```
.container-center {
    width: (whatever you like, ex; 700px or 80%);
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: block;
;
```

Then you can give the one with the scrolling this:

```
.container-scroll {
    width: -webkit-calc(700px - 16px);
}
```

I'm guessing 16px for the scroll width. Also you'll want to do the rest of the vendor prefixes `-moz, -o` and just normal `calc` for IE

Comment: Yes, this would indeed fix it for IE and Chrome under Windows. But this also breaks it for Chrome, FF, ... under OSx and on ipad, iphone, ... (where the scrollbars are not included in the calculation)

Comment: So subtract more than 16px or whatever